# How to enable the TwinCAT remote status icon in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, twincat

I always used to have a TwinCAT remote status icon in the bottom bar of Visual Studio (2017 Community).

[image]

However, after a recent update of Visual Studio this icon disappeared. How can I get this icon back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this icon back by going to **Tools > Options > Environment > General** and make sure the option "Enable rich client visual experience" is selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The given solution was not working for me, as an alternative go to: `C:\TwinCAT\3.1\System\TcSysUI.exe` and create a shortcut from that exe file, after that paste it in the start up folder.

To find the start up folder just type:  `win + r`, it will open the following window

[image: win+r]

In the text box write the following line: `shell:startup` and copy the short cut to the opened folder:

[image: startup folder]

After a restart the icon was visible to me.